# Archive parameter not looping

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the `wp_get_archives` function to display a list of posts on my sidebar. Currently this does work as intended.

I want to build upon this sidebar by displaying `get_the_title()` and `get_the_excerpt()`. these also work.

***However they are only displaying the current title and excerpt and not the corresponding title and excerpt to the current post.***

**Example:**

> Post 1 displays post 1's title and excerpt.
>
> Post 2 displays post 1's title and excerpt.

Here is my full sidebar:

```
<aside id= "homeSideBar">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) { 
            the_post(); ?>
    <?php }}
    wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'postbypost', 'limit' => 10, 'after' => "<img class='showExcerpt' src=\"" . get_template_directory_uri() ."/images/plus-circle.png\"><div class='postExcerpt'><h1 class='fitHeadliner'>" . get_the_title() . "</h1><p>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p><div class='hideExcerpt'>X</div></div>" ) ); ?>
    
    <a href="/index.php?page_id=4">...</a>

</aside>
```

How can I make my posts display their corresponding titles and excerpts?

Comment: can you please explain the question more.. you have placed the get_the_title() and get_the_excerpt() function outside the while loop.. Please tell what exactly needs to be the output

Comment: When Placing the `wp_get_archives()` function within the loop, it displays the archives as many times as there are posts. Currently the function returns a list of posts linking to each of the last 10. I would like to add excerpt and title using the `after` argument of `wp_get_archives`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as my sidebar gets more involved, I thought it best to refactor and create a `sidebar.php` template.

Within my `sidebar.php` template I use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) within `get_posts()` you can use [setup_postdata( $post )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to globalize post information like `the_excerpt()`, `the_title()`, etc.